# Display object and list of object

Tags: thymeleaf

I use spring boot with thymeleaf 3

I try to display a bean

In my controller I have

```
public String getNewCarsTemplate(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("cars", new Cars());
}
```

In cars I have

```
@OneToOne
private Cities cities;  // field id and name

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "car")
private List<Locations> locations = new ArrayList<>();
```

In location I have

```
private Integer id;

private String name;

@ManyToOne
private Suppliers supplier;
```

In my thymeleaf fragment

```
<form id="carsForm" action="#" th:action="@{/template/new/cars}" th:object="${cars}" th:method="post">
    ...
    <input type="hidden" th:field="*{cities.id}" > 
   <input id="carsCities" class="form-control js-typeahead" type="search" placeholder="Type partial value" th:field="*{cities.name}" autocomplete="off" >
    ...
    <table id="locationsTable" class="table table-striped table-hover responsive">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th th:text="#{name}">Name</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr th:each="car, stat : ${cars}">
                <td> 
                    <input type="hidden" th:id="${'locationId-'+stat.index}"  th:field="*{car.locations[__${stat.index}__].id}" />
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" th:id="${'locationName-'+stat.index}" th:placeholder="#{name.placeholder}" placeholder="Name" th:field="*{car.locations[__${stat.index}__].name}" />
                </td>
                <td class="align-middle"> <i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

</form>
```

When I try to display this fragment I get

> org.attoparser.ParseException: Exception evaluating SpringEL
>   expression: "cities.id"  Caused by:
>   org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E:
>   Property or field 'id' cannot be found on object of type
>   'java.util.ArrayList' - maybe not public or not valid?

Comment: interesting... Try setting some default value on that input tag

Answer (score 0):

Could you try substituting

```
<input type="hidden" th:field="*{cities.id}" >
```

with

```
<input type="hidden" th:field="*{cities?.id}" >
```

and let me know if this works for you.
The  '?' operator will address the problem that in the new Cars() object the cities is null